# Two tables in two columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

I want the two tables to be next to each other without overlapping, but for some reason they both seem to be centered on the page even when using the `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column {.3\textwidth}
        
        \begin{table}
        
        
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        75 \\
        95 64 \\
        17 47 82 \\
        18 35 87 10 \\
        20 04 82 47 65 \\
        19 01 23 75 03 34 \\
        88 02 77 73 07 63 67 \\
        99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92 \\
        41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33 \\
        41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29 \\
        53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14 \\
        70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57 \\
        91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 \\
        63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 \\
        04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        
        \column {.3\textwidth}
        
        \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 \\
        63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 \\
        04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to place two `tabular` envrionments side by side on a beamer frame, there is no need for the `columns` environment. If you don't want to add a caption, the `table` environment is superfluous, as well (its typical floating behavior is nevertheless disabled in a `beamer` document).

To make sure, the two tabulars appear side by side, make sure there is no empty line between them. In the following MWE, I used `\hfill` to place the first table near the left margin and the second table near the right margin. Additionally, your tables are too large to fit on the slide side by side. I therefore used `\tiny` in order to reduce the font size and with it the widths of both tabulars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\tiny
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        75 \\
        95 64 \\
        17 47 82 \\
        18 35 87 10 \\
        20 04 82 47 65 \\
        19 01 23 75 03 34 \\
        88 02 77 73 07 63 67 \\
        99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92 \\
        41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33 \\
        41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29 \\
        53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14 \\
        70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57 \\
        91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 \\
        63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 \\
        04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 \\
        63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 \\
        04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no way to have TeX automatically adjust the size of the numbers in the table to get it to fit the two tables next two each other?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is simply that the text is too large. You can also put everything in one table to save having to deal with columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
        \begin{table}
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        75 &\\
        95 64 &\\
        17 47 82 &\\
        18 35 87 10 &\\
        20 04 82 47 65& \\
        19 01 23 75 03 34& \\
        88 02 77 73 07 63 67 &  91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 \\
        99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92 &  63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31 \\
        41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33 & 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 \\
        41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29& \\
        53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14& \\
        70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57& \\
        91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48 &\\
        63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31& \\
        04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23 &\\
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]